# Solving a mathematical diamond in Java

Tags: java, math

After doing some intense Googling for a Diamond Problem solver in java, all I could find was the OOP diamond problem. That's not what I'm after. What I'm looking for is a simple function in java to find the solution to a diamond problem.

A diamond problem can be expressed like this:

A = C * D,

B = C + D

So, if:

A = 10, B = 7

C = 5, D = 2

What I'm attempting to do is solve a diamond problem in java quickly and effectively. I've tried nested for loops, but they're extremely inefficient due to the nature of the program.

If anyone has any ideas, I would love to hear them.

Thanks!

Comment: Who said the solutions had to be integers?

Comment: :) prime A = 7, B = 8, C = 1, D = 7

Comment: if A is nonzero and B is 0, then it is unsolvable.

Comment: if A = 1300837, B = 0, C = i*sqrt(1300837), D = -i*sqrt(1300837)

Comment: You're imagining things, @durron597.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we observe the following algebra:

`B^2 - 4A = (C^2 + 2CD + C^2) - 4CD = (C^2 - 2CD + D^2) = (C-D)^2`

Then we can quickly and easily make this function:

```
public static double[] diamondSolve(double a, double b) {
    double temp = b * b - 4 * a;
    double difference = Math.sqrt(temp); // difference = C - D

    double[] retArray = new double[2];

    // (b + difference) / 2 = (C + D + C - D) / 2 = 2C / 2 = C
    retArray[0] = (b + difference) / 2;

    // B - C = C + D - C  = D
    retArray[1] = b - retArray[0];

    return retArray;
}
```

By the way, this will generate problems if `4A` is bigger than `B^2`... in that case the answers are imaginary anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a pair of simultaneous equations and can be solved analytically without recourse to number crunching.

Rearrange your second line to get `C = B - D` and substitute into the first line. This gives a quadratic in `D`:

```
A = D * (B - D)
```

By the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula), we have a pair of solutions for `D`:

```
D = (B +/- sqrt(B^2 - 4*A)) / 2
```

Now substitute these solutions back into line 2 to solve for `C`.

Comment: C = B / D ?  Don't you mean C = B - D ?

Comment: Yeah, this answer has a number of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to do the algebra for you, but just solve for `c` and `d` in terms of `a` and `b`

so something like

```
`C = A + B/A`
```

disclimer, i just made the expression above up, but the same concept follows.  you can do your own algebra.

maybe you can do some sort of switch statement Depending on what values you know.  there are 4 choose 2( that's like 6) different cases

Comment: This wasn't in the question, but typically the constraint is to find an integer answer.

Comment: You will end up getting something like this: `A/(B-C)=C` which is unsolvable. This answer will not work.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob  I did say in the answer that i made the specific formula up,  specifically told the op **"You can do your own algebra"** and i was just writing how to translate your math solution into a java solution

Comment: ...although it is mathematically impossible to derive a formula which is solved for C or D in this case.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob: actually there is a formula. See my answer

Comment: @durron597 whoa, your answer is confusing